# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: [](0) ! What am I doing Wrong here?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The following NoSuchMethodError
> was thrown building: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver:
> null Tried calling:

main.dart

```
void main() {
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(title: 'Email Client App'),
    );
  }
}
```

home_screen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: MessagesScreen());
  }
}
```

message_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:email_client_app/models/message.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MessagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessagesScreenState createState() => _MessagesScreenState();
}

class _MessagesScreenState extends State<MessagesScreen> {
  Future loadMessageFromAsset() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return await rootBundle.loadString("data/message.json");
  }

  Future<List<Message>> getMessagesFromAsset() async {
    String jsonString = await loadMessageFromAsset();
    List<dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonString);
    List<Message> messages =
        data.map((data) => Message.fromJson(data)).toList();
    return messages;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getMessagesFromAsset();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getMessagesFromAsset(),
        builder: (context, messages) {
          List<Message> messageList = messages.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

** This is where the error is caught!**

```
              var message = messageList[index];
```

--

```
              return ListTile(
                isThreeLine: true,
                leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text('ND')),
                title: Text(messageList[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(
                  message.body,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.more_horiz_outlined,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

message.dart (Message models class). # Retrieving local data-source from message.json

```
class Message {
  Message({this.title, this.body});
  String title, body;

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Message(title: data['title'], body: data['body']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {'title': title, 'body': body};
  }
}
```

message.json

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. "
    }
]
```

Comment: Also I wanted to move  'loadMessageFromAsset()' & 'getMessagesFromAsset()' into a different file under services. In that case, how do I grab its data in the message_screen.dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that I think you are doing wrong.

- You are calling the method `getMessagesFromAsset` at two places: `initState` & `FutureBuilder`. Remove from `initState`.
- Your method `getMessageskFromAsset` might need to use a different variable name in the map method:

  ```
  Future<List<Message>> getMessagesFromAsset() async {
       String jsonString = await loadMessageFromAsset();
       List<dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonString);
       List<Message> messages =
           data.map((messageData) => Message.fromJson(messageData)).toList(); // here
       return messages;
     }
  ```
- Check whether the `messages` list is `null` or not.

  ```
  List<Message> messageList = messages.data ?? [];
  ```
- Inside `ListView.builder`, you are using a fixed value `5`, which will lead to index out of bounds exception.

  ```
  return ListView.builder(
       itemCount: messages?.length ?? 0, // Use messages.length instead of `5`
  ```

Comment: # itemCount is embarrassingly missed.
# Checking the messageList for null value was an excellent suggestion. Just a clarification though, already a connectionState condition is working so why do we need to check if the list is empty?

Comment: Also I wanted to move 'loadMessageFromAsset()' & 'getMessagesFromAsset()' into a different file under services. In that case, how do I grab its data in the message_screen.dart?

Comment: I don't see any `connectionState` condition in the above code. Still, if the server responded with an empty list, you should be able to handle that condition also. That's why you should check if the list is empty & return the appropriate widget according to it.

Comment: In order to get data in the `message_screen.dart` from other files, you should pass the data as arguments to the `MessageScreen` widget.

Comment: I updated my code base with the connectionState with a CircularProgressiveIndicator widget. Also moved the functions for loading and getting the data to services. Got it running now.

Comment: That's really great to hear. If you found my answer helpful, you can upvote or mark the answer as selected.

Answer (score 1):

Return indicator or anything when connection state is waiting.

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: getMessagesFromAsset(),
        builder: (context, messages) {

          // add this one
          if (messages.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text("Loading...");
          }
          List<Message> messageList = messages.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                isThreeLine: true,
                leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text('ND')),
                title: Text(messageList[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(
                  message.body,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.more_horiz_outlined,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
```